# Shorter way for content script to communicate with other content script on google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

So i am trying to build a web page that can effect other web page. For example, if i press a button on web page A, it would automatically run a set of actions (ex. click the menu -> manipulate a form -> save) on web page B. And yes, the action needs to be on web page A, not on popup.html

My idea was to have 2 content script for each web page that i want to manipulate and a background script. If some action was performed on web page A, content script A would send a message to the background script and the background script would send a message to content script B. Is there a shorter and concise way to do what i want?

Comment: You can use extension storage chrome.storage.local to share data between the content scripts without the need for a background script. Furthermore, if the pages have the same URL origin you can use the standard DOM BroadcastChannel API.

Comment: @wOxxOm how would script B know when script A manipulate data from storage? How would it listen to that event? For this case, the url of the pages are different

Comment: Yes, there are events, see the documentation.